# Android custom outline renders weird looking elevation shadow

Tags: android, android-elevation

I have a custom view based on FrameLayout shown in fullscreen (as part of Android's SystemUI package) and I use canvas to draw some stuff.

Now I want a single element (one of the circles I draw) in this view to cast some kind of shadow. So I've added a custom outline to let the framework render the shadow for me. Unfortunately this shadow looks kinda weird (surrounding circular line) and I am pretty clueless about what could be causing this issue.

Did anyone face a similar issue or knows how to solve this? Thanks!

MWE:

```
public class Menu extends FrameLayout {

    private int mRadius;

    public Menu(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mRadius = context.getResources()
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.menu_radius);

        setElevation(context.getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.menu_elevation));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        setOutlineProvider(new CustomOutline(w, h));
    }

    private class CustomOutline extends ViewOutlineProvider {

        private int mWidth;
        private int mHeight;

        public CustomOutline(int w, int h) {
            mWidth = w;
            mHeight = h;
        }

        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            outline.setOval(-mRadius, -mRadius, mRadius, mRadius);
            outline.offset(mWidth/2, mHeight/2);
        }
    }
}
```

Weird looking shadow:

[image: Weird looking elevation shadow]

Comment: I think, if the circle is drawn on the canvas the shadows are scattered. Are you using `onDraw()`?

Comment: Yes I'm using onDraw(), but in the MWE I didn't even draw anything yet. I just set elevation and the outline provider. :/

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code, elevation shadows are drawn by the system like this. These artifacts are only visible when the shape you draw over them is transparent or translucent. An opaque shape will cover them, like on this example:

[image: Elevation shadows with an opaque shape]

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was always under the impression that the empty space is meant to be filled with an opaque shape :/